# Parsing iw wlan0 scan output

Tags: bash, parsing, sed, awk

I wrote wlan manager script to handle open/ad-hoc/wep/wpa2 networks. Now im trying to parse iw wlan0 scan output to get nice scan feature to my script. My goal is to get output like this :

```
SSID        channel     signal      encryption
wlan-ap     6           70%         wpa2-psk
test        1           55%         wep
```

What i have achived already is output like this :

```
$ iw wlan0 scan | grep 'SSID\|freq\|signal\|capability' | tac
SSID: Koti783
signal: -82.00 dBm
capability: ESS Privacy ShortPreamble SpectrumMgmt ShortSlotTime (0x0531)
freq: 2437
```

I have been trying to study bash/sed/awk but havent found yet a way to achieve what im trying. So what is good way to achieve that?

Comment: the input provides no sufficient information to achieve that output

Comment: Please note that iw's own help page reads "Do NOT screenscrape this tool, we don't consider its output stable."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is my final solution based of [Sudo_O answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17810551/1066031):

```
$1 == "BSS" {
    MAC = $2
    wifi[MAC]["enc"] = "Open"
}
$1 == "SSID:" {
    wifi[MAC]["SSID"] = $2
}
$1 == "freq:" {
    wifi[MAC]["freq"] = $NF
}
$1 == "signal:" {
    wifi[MAC]["sig"] = $2 " " $3
}
$1 == "WPA:" {
    wifi[MAC]["enc"] = "WPA"
}
$1 == "WEP:" {
    wifi[MAC]["enc"] = "WEP"
}
END {
    printf "%s\t\t%s\t%s\t\t%s\n","SSID","Frequency","Signal","Encryption"

    for (w in wifi) {
        printf "%s\t\t%s\t\t%s\t%s\n",wifi[w]["SSID"],wifi[w]["freq"],wifi[w]["sig"],wifi[w]["enc"]
    }
}'
```

Output:

```
$ sudo iw wlan0 scan | awk -f scan.awk
SSID        Frequency   Signal      Encryption
netti       2437        -31.00 dBm  Open
Koti783     2437        -84.00 dBm  WPA
WLAN-AP     2462        -85.00 dBm  WPA
```

Comment: Nice work, glad you managed to get a full solution and post the answer back for everybody +1. Now you have enough reputation you can +1 my solution :)

Comment: There is no "WEP" IE, so your solution does not work to detect WEP encryption.

Comment: As @nicolas-marchildon mentioned above, you need to install gawk in the Raspberry Pi to be able to run this.

Comment: I wrote a script based off this one. Not perfect and it might have some bugs, but it works okay for my use case: https://gist.github.com/miyalys/dfc052607e729e1a6c845d28c1cb0488

Comment: For the sake of completion, the ' in the code is to be removed to make it runnable. 
Also, the code does not work with mawk, check with `sudo update-alternatives --config awk` to see what you are running or just with `awk --version`

Comment: you can check for WPA2 when changing `WEP` to `RSN`

Answer (score 9):

it's generally bad practice to try parsing complex output of programs intended for humans to read (rather than machines to parse).

e.g. the output of `iw` might change depending on the language settings of the system and/or the version of `iw`, leaving you with a "manager" that only works on your development machine.

instead you might use the same interface that `iw` uses to get it's information: the library backend [libnl](http://www.carisma.slowglass.com/~tgr/libnl/)

you might also want to have a look at the `wireless-tools` (`iwconfig`, `iwlist`,...) that use the [libiw](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Jean_Tourrilhes/Linux/Tools.html) library.

Comment: Please note that iw's own help page reads "Do NOT screenscrape this tool, we don't consider its output stable."

Comment: Thanks for pointing to libnl. Also the following libnl example in Python might be relevant for those reluctant to compile things https://github.com/Robpol86/libnl/blob/master/example_scan_access_points.py

Answer (score 5):

Here is an `GNU awk` script to get you going that grabs the SSIDs and the channel for each unique BSS:

```
/^BSS / {
    MAC = $2
}
/SSID/ {
    wifi[MAC]["SSID"] = $2
}
/primary channel/ {
    wifi[MAC]["channel"] = $NF
}

# Insert new block here

END {
    printf "%s\t\t%s\n","SSID","channel"

    for (w in wifi) {
        printf "%s\t\t%s\n",wifi[w]["SSID"],wifi[w]["channel"]
    }
}
```

It should be easy for you to add the new blocks for signal and encryption considering all the studying you have been doing.

Save the script to file such as `wifi.awk` and run like:

```
$ sudo iw wlan0 scan | awk -f wifi.awk
```

The output will be in the formatted requested:

```
SSID        channel
wlan-ap     6
test        1
```

Comment: Thats very nice and useful. Thank you. I just cant find out how to show the AP:s encryption.

Comment: This is great if you are lucky to use gawk instead of traditional Awk. The awk command in OpenWrt comes from Busybox and does not support multidimensional arrays.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simple Bash function which uses exclusively Bash internals and spawns only one sub-shell:

```
#!/bin/bash 
function iwScan() {
   # disable globbing to avoid surprises
   set -o noglob
   # make temporary variables local to our function
   local AP S
   # read stdin of the function into AP variable
   while read -r AP; do
     ## print lines only containing needed fields
     [[ "${AP//'SSID: '*}" == '' ]] && printf '%b' "${AP/'SSID: '}\n"
     [[ "${AP//'signal: '*}" == '' ]] && ( S=( ${AP/'signal: '} ); printf '%b' "${S[0]},";)
   done
   set +o noglob
}

iwScan <<< "$(iw wlan0 scan)"
```

Output:

```
-66.00,FRITZ!Box 7312
-56.00,ALICE-WLAN01
-78.00,o2-WLAN93
-78.00,EasyBox-7A2302
-62.00,dlink
-74.00,EasyBox-59DF56
-76.00,BELAYS_Network
-82.00,o2-WLAN20
-82.00,BPPvM
```

The function can be easily modified to provide additional fields by adding a necessary filter into the while read -r AP while-loop, eg:

```
[[ "${AP//'last seen: '*}" == '' ]] && ( S=( ${AP/'last seen: '} ); printf '%b' "${S[0]},";)
```

Output:

```
-64.00,1000,FRITZ!Box 7312
-54.00,492,ALICE-WLAN01
-76.00,2588,o2-WLAN93
-78.00,652,LN8-Gast
-72.00,2916,WHITE-BOX
-66.00,288,ALICE-WLAN
-78.00,800,EasyBox-59DF56
-80.00,720,EasyBox-7A2302
-84.00,596,ALICE-WLAN08
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using such solution for openwrt:

wlan_scan.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo iw dev wlan0 scan | awk -f wlan_scan.awk | sort
```

wlan_scan.awk

```
/^BSS/ {
    mac = gensub ( /^BSS[[:space:]]*([0-9a-fA-F:]+).*?$/, "\\1", "g", $0 );
}
/^[[:space:]]*signal:/ {
    signal = gensub ( /^[[:space:]]*signal:[[:space:]]*(\-?[0-9.]+).*?$/, "\\1", "g", $0 );
}
/^[[:space:]]*SSID:/ {
    ssid = gensub ( /^[[:space:]]*SSID:[[:space:]]*([^\n]*).*?$/, "\\1", "g", $0 );
    printf ( "%s %s %s\n", signal, mac, ssid );
}
```

result

```
-62.00 c8:64:c7:54:d9:05 a
-72.00 70:72:3c:1c:af:17 b
-81.00 78:f5:fd:be:33:cb c
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in the awk script above.

The following code will not work if the SSID has spaces in the name.  The received result will be the first token of the SSID name only.

```
$1 == "SSID:" {
    wifi[MAC]["SSID"] = $2
}
```

When printing $0, $1, $2:

```
$0:     SSID: DIRECT-82-HP OfficeJet 8700
$1: SSID:
$2: DIRECT-82-HP
```

One possibly solution is to take a substr of $0 which contains leading spaces, the token "SSID: " and the provided multi-token network name.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: This is hardly an answer to the question, but rather a followup question to a specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've taken awk code from [Ari Malinen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17880517/3914764) and reworked it a bit, because iw output is not stable and changes, also there are other issues like spaces in SSID. I put it on [github](https://github.com/n3tr4k/awk_iw_grab) in case if I'll change it in the future.

```
#!/usr/bin/env awk -f

$1 ~ /^BSS/ {
    if($2 !~ /Load:/) { #< Escape "BBS Load:" line
        gsub("(\\(.*|:)", "", $2)
        MAC = toupper($2)
        wifi[MAC]["enc"] = "OPEN"
        wifi[MAC]["WPS"] = "no"
        wifi[MAC]["wpa1"] = ""
        wifi[MAC]["wpa2"] = ""
        wifi[MAC]["wep"] = ""
    }
}
$1 == "SSID:" {
    # Workaround spaces in SSID
    FS=":" #< Changing field separator on ":", it should be
           #  forbidded sign for SSID name
    $0=$0
    sub(" ", "", $2) #< remove first whitespace
    wifi[MAC]["SSID"] = $2
    FS=" "
    $0=$0
}
$1 == "capability:" {
    for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
        if($i ~ /0x[0-9]{4}/) {
            gsub("(\\(|\\))", "", $i)
            if (and(strtonum($i), 0x10)) 
                wifi[MAC]["wep"] = "WEP"
        }
    }
}
$1 == "WPA:" {
    wifi[MAC]["wpa1"] = "WPA1"
}
$1 == "RSN:" {
    wifi[MAC]["wpa2"] = "WPA2"
}
$1 == "WPS:" {
    wifi[MAC]["WPS"] = "yes"
}
$1 == "DS" {
    wifi[MAC]["Ch"] = $5
}
$1 == "signal:" {
    match($2, /-([0-9]{2})\.00/, m)
    wifi[MAC]["Sig"] = m[1]
}
$1 == "TSF:" {
    gsub("(\\(|d|,)", "", $4)
    match($5, /([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):/, m)
    day = $4
    hour = m[1]
    min = m[2]
    wifi[MAC]["TSF"] = day"d"hour"h"min"m"
}
END {
    for (w in wifi) {
        if (wifi[w]["wep"]) {
            if (wifi[w]["wpa1"] || wifi[w]["wpa2"])
                wifi[w]["enc"] = wifi[w]["wpa1"]wifi[w]["wpa2"]
            else
                wifi[w]["enc"] = "WEP"
        }
        printf "%s:%s:%s:%s:%s:%s:%s\n", w, wifi[w]["SSID"], wifi[w]["enc"], \
               wifi[w]["WPS"], wifi[w]["Ch"], wifi[w]["Sig"], wifi[w]["TSF"]
    }
}
```

Output:

```
A5FEF2C499BB:test-ssid2:OPEN:no:9:43:0d00h00m
039EFACA9A8B:test-ssid2:WPA1:no:9:33:0d00h00m
038BF3C1988B:test-ssid2:WPA2:no:9:35:0d00h00m
028EF3C2997B:test-ssid2:WPA1:no:9:35:0d00h03m
```

if you wonder what `if($2 !~ /Load:/)` does, well on some routers there might be  "BSS Load:" string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jc](https://kellyjonbrazil.github.io/jc/docs/parsers/iw_scan) (JSON Convert)

> jc JSONifies the output of many CLI tools, file-types, and common strings for easier parsing in scripts.

```
$ iw dev wlan0 scan | jc --iw-scan
```

or

```
$ jc iw dev wlan0 scan
```